# \trim@spaces already defined

Tags: moodle

I have been using the `moodle.sty` package with great success (using WinEdt & MiKTeX), but suddenly the compiler complains about the following error:

> Command \trim@spaces already defined.

All LaTeX files that loads the `moodle.sty` file give the same error.

I can't seem to find where this double definition occurs. Does `moodle` call the `trimspaces` package?

Comment: you should show a small example that can be used for tests.

Comment: The `moodle` package indeed loads `trimspaces`.